# Are there integers x, y, z such that x^3+y^3+z^3=1234567894? (Hint: Think about the corresponding congruence modulo 9.)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I see that 1234567894 is not divisible by 9 because the digits add up to 49 which is not divisible by 9. This led me to believe that when adding up the cubes of 3 integers x, y, z, we get that x^3+y^3+z^3 is congruent to 4(mod 9). But we want to show that we cannot get a remainder of 4 when adding up the cubes of these three integers. Not really sure where to go from here. I considered proof by cases with even and odd numbers but that seems inefficient as there are a lot of different cases to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The only possible values of a cube modulo $9$ will be $\{0,1,-1\}$  (*or equivalently $\{0,1,8\}$*)  (*You should prove this*)

Thus, the only possible results of the sum of three cubes modulo $9$ are...

Comment: So then if we add different combinations of the elements of {0, 1, 8} we cannot get 4 and that's it?

Comment: @Matt quite.  The possible sums range from $-3$ to $3$, and $4$ is not a possible sum.

Answer (score 3):

It's not hard to write down a list of all the cubes mod 9.  (Just compute all 9 of them.)  Now it's not hard to list all possible sums of three of these cubes....